# java - how do external changes to the system clock affect java util timer?

Tags: java, timer

I've got a bunch of timertasks scheduled on a timer. Some of them are run once, others are fixedrate repeating tasks.

If the system clock is modified externally after things have been scheduled, how are the scheduled tasks affected?

Answer (score 2):

If by "the system clock," you mean the clock that keeps human-time, then that is independent of any timers you are running in your app, unless they in turn depend specifically on the time of day.

Comment: To clarify, I mean the OS clock (windows or linux). Once a fixed rate timertask has been executed once, does the date object used to schedule the first run time become irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

And of course if you mean "Time of Day" (like class Date), then the change to the system clock *will* be reflected in your objects.